# how to insert the date (today) in the middle of a document

Tags: datetime

So the question is simple: Instead of having the date in the title, how do you manage to put the current date in the middle of the text, within the document?

Thanks

Comment: Simply use `\today`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\today`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\today

\end{document}
```

If you want to change the formatting, there's a number of packages which you could use, for example, [`datetime`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datetime).